# #REF! ao excluir celulas em uma outra planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Bom dia,

Tenho um arquivo Excel com duas planilha, na 'Plan1' todos os dados são excluídos, e uma MACRO que fiz, importa um arquivo TXT e popula a 'Plan1', inserindo dados e cálculos. Na 'Plan2' os dados são fixos e pega como referencia os dados da 'Plan1', porem quando os dados da 'Plan1' são excluídos, todas as referencias são perdidas na 'Plan2', mostrando o erro '#REF!'.

Alguém sabe alguma formula que não use essa referencia que leva em consideração as células excluídas? Algo onde '=Plan1!A5' sempre sera '=Plan1!A5' mesmo que o '=Plan1!A5' tenha sido excluído.

Já me antecedo, o $(cifrão) não serve pra isso.

Comment: Uma solução seria reescrever a 'Plan2' com uma macro assim q a 'Plan1' for finalizada :/
Mas não queria ter que fazer isso...

Comment: Qualquer referência a Plan1 será substituída por #REF! pelo Excel assim que a planilha for removida. Não vejo como fazer o Excel manter a formula referenciando a ela após ela ter sido excluída.  A sua solução me parece ser adequada e qualquer outra deve ser parecida com essa.

Answer (score 2):

A solução, vamos dizer que é a mais fácil, foi reescrever a segunda planilha com uma macro. Já que ela é meio estática deu certo dessa maneira:

```
Sheets("Plan2").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(PLAN1!RC[2]>0,PLAN1!RC[15]>0),PLAN1!RC[1],0)"

#... RESTANTE DO CÓDIGO ...

Range("O5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-9]=""CC"",RC[-4]*-97.25%,IF(RC[-9]=""CA"",RC[-7]-RC[-4],IF(RC[-9]=""MX"",RC[-7]-RC[-4])))"

Range("A5:O5").Select
#COPIA TODA A LINHA PARA AS DEMAIS
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:O309"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Sheets("PLAN1").Select
```

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

$(cifrão) serve para fixar a posição.

Se você escrever =Plan1!A5 e copiar essa formula para a colunas seguintes, 
ela será substituída por =Plan1!B5, =Plan1!C5.. e se copiar para as linhas seguintes, então serão substituídas por =Plan1!A6, =Plan1!A7....

Se você quiser fixar a coluna você escreve =Plan1!$A5 e pode copiar para outras colunas que permanecerá igual e fixa a linha com =Plan1!A$5, ou pode fixar os dois = Plan1!$A$5. Independentemente de onde essa formula for copiada ela sempre apontará para o mesmo lugar.

Mas a Plan1 esta lá como referência e será substituída por #REF! em todos os lugares que ela aparecer assim que a planilha for removida.

Comment: Eu conheço como funciona o $(cifrão). A Plan1 não é "removida/excluída" o que acontece é que o conteúdo é apagado e a MACRO exclui algumas linhas e algumas colunas, e isso gera o erro "#REF!"... Preciso de um $(cifrão) que mantenha a formula inteiro independente do que foi excluído na "Plan1".

Comment: Por que você não exclui apenas o conteúdo da célula, sem excluir a linha ou coluna?